# 7zip compressing the same file slightly different results

Tags: 7zip

I am using 7za command line

File dfat_clist.xls in directory 2010_05_07

The same dfat_clist.xls in directory 2010_05_08

Zips are created in the same directory where the xls files resides

```
string pars = "a -tzip \"" + Path.Combine( SourceDir,ZipName) + "\" \"" + Path.Combine( SourceDir, Mask ) + "\"" ;
```

Parameters given to 7za are full paths for zip and xls. 
For some reason a couple of bytes are different A7 and A8 values for directories 2010_05_07 and 2010_05_8 respectively. How to achieve identical results and out of curiosity what causes this problem.

Comment: Because I am saving zip versions in database if zip changed and don't want to change existing logic which worked with winrar.

Comment: Ah I see now. I would test a few things like does renaming the root directory the file is in change the output then check the same with different date modified, date created... of the file as these will get encoded too.

Comment: I wouldn't advise this by the way as different versions of 7-zip and different computers may give different output. Encoding algorithms can give different output based on the time it takes to find optimal coding.

The diff should be done by extracting the file from the db and comparing with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question you have two identical XLS files in different folders and you want to know why the two 7zip'd files are different?

Assuming that you aren't storing the directory name in the zip then you've probably hit the same problem I had (see '[7zip produces different output from identical input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136783/7zip-produces-different-output-from-identical-input)').

The accepted answer from [Mofi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3074564/mofi) might help.