# 7zip produces different output from identical input

Tags: 7zip

I'm using command line 7zip to zip up the contents of a folder (in Windows) thus:

```
7za a myzip.zip * -tzip -r
```

I've discovered that running *exactly* the same command line twice will produce two different ZIP files - they've got the same size but if you run a binary compare (ie fc /b file1.zip file2.zip) they are different.  To complicate matters it seems that if you make the two zips in rapid succession then they *are* the same.  But if you do them on different days or separated by a few hours they are not.

I presume that there's a date/time stamp in the ZIP file somewhere but I can't find anything on the 7zip site to confirm that.

Assuming I'm right does anyone know how to suppress the date/time?  Or is something else causing the binaries to be different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

7-zip has the switch `-m` with parameter `tc` which has value `on` by default if not specified on command line.

With `-mtc=on` all 3 dates of a file stored on an NTFS partition are stored in the archive:

- the last modification time,
- the creation time, and also
- the last access time.

See in help of 7-zip the page with title [-m (Set compression Method) switch](http://sevenzip.sourceforge.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/method.htm).

The last access time of the files is most likely responsible for the differences between the archive files.

You have to append `-mtc=off` to avoid storage of the NTFS timestamps in archive file.

Comment: Ah, many thanks.  Saves me much time unnecessarily copying files over a slow internet connection.  Works perfectly.